# Enable Cors Policy with SignalR in asp.net core web application

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, console, cors, client

I have a signalR hub class that contains methods and I created a client console application to test that method either its working or not it works fine without implementing cors in server after implementing cors`

I want that it didnt gives access to localhost only give access to specified url but it still gives access to localhost and connect to server How I solve this issue. [[This is cors policy t hat I add in program.cs class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uj9O.png)]

[image]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEBq8.png)

[image]

And this is client console application that have to block when accesss from localhost but it still gives data`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nqxt.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1, Change `WithOrigins` to allow all, like below:

```
    builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AdminCorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyMethod()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials();
    }));
```

2, change the middleware order like below

```
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    // move to here
    app.UseCors("AdminCorsPolicy");

    app.UseElmah();

    app.UseRouting();
```

3, Remove the attribute in DashboardHub.

---

**Summary**

After check your sample code, I found it seems you are using wrong `params` in `WithOrigins`, and the middleware order also not correct.

In your scenario, if there are other web applications (the URL is http://a.com), then we need to add http://a.com in WithOrigins so that `a.com` can access our signalR Server.